# How to retrieve comments from an owl file using Jena API?

Tags: rdf, jena, ontology, owl, protege

currently I am doing a project on Ontology Based Information Retrieval. I have created the base ontology using the ontology editor, Protege and obtained the file , say family.owl .Basically i want to perform a search function .The user provides the search term  and then it is searched with the individuals in the ontology . If a match is found ,then print the comment associated with that individual .I have used the Jena API to parse the ontology .So far i am successful in obtaining the subject , predicate and object associated with each resource but i am not able to get the comment associate with each resource . A part of family.owl looks like this

```
<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/9/family.owl#Beth -->
<owl:Thing rdf:about="#Beth">
    <rdfs:comment>Beth is the Daughter of Adam . She is the Sister of Chuck .  
     She is the Mother of Dotty & Edward . She is the Aunt of Fran & Greg.
    </rdfs:comment>
    <isChildOf rdf:resource="#Adam"/>
    <isSiblingOf rdf:resource="#Chuck"/>
</owl:Thing>
```

So when i search for Beth ,I should get the comment associated with it ie.Beth is the Daughter of Adam . She is the Sister of Chuck.She is the Mother of Dotty & Edward . She is the Aunt of Fran & Greg.The code i have used to get the subject,predicate and object is as follows

```
    StmtIterator iter=model.listStatements();          
    while(iter.hasNext())
    {
        Statement stmt=iter.nextStatement();
        String subject=stmt.getSubject().toString;                             
        String predicate=stmt.getPredicate().toString();            
        String object=stmt.getObject().toString();
        ...
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `rdfs:comment` should be there as one of the predicates that you get (its `toString`, which you are advised not to rely on incidentally, will be: `http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#comment`). If it's not there, then either your code isn't what you are showing us or the data is not what you quote. Since I couldn't find the ontology you refer to, we have no way of checking that.

An easier way to do what you want would be to use the [Jena ontology API](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/ontology/index.html). Using the ontology API, you could do something like this (I haven't run this code, but it should work):

```
OntModel m = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel( OntModelSpec.OWL_MEM );
FileManager.get().readModel( m, "... your input file here ..." );

String NS = "http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/9/family.owl#";
Individual beth = m.getIndividual( NS + "Beth" );
String comment = beth.getComment();
```

Comment: In that case, please mark the answer as accepted by clicking on the green check mark. That tells other users that you have found an answer to your question.

Comment: in beth.getComment() what parameter is passed